# @Version column is not working out of the box with spring data jdbc

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

I have my version column defined like this

```
@org.springframework.data.annotation.Version
protected long version;
```

With Spring Data JDBC it's always trying to INSERT. Updates are not happening. When I debug I see that, `PersistentEntityIsNewStrategy` is being used which is the default strategy. It has `isNew()` method to determine the state of the entity being persisted. I do see that version and id are used for this determination.

But my question is who is responsible to increment the version column after every save, so that when the second time `.save()` is called, the `isNew()` method can return false.

Should we do fire a `BeforeSaveEvent` and handle the incrementation of Version column? Would that be good enough to handle the `OptimisticLock` ?

**Edit**
I added an ApplicationListener to listen to BeforeSaveEvent like this.

```
public ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent> incrementingVersion() {
    return event -> {
        Object entity = event.getEntity();
        if (BaseDataModel.class.isAssignableFrom(entity.getClass())) {
            BaseDataModel baseDataModel = (BaseDataModel) entity;
            Long version = baseDataModel.getVersion();
            if (version == null) {
                baseDataModel.setVersion(0L);
            } else {
                baseDataModel.setVersion(version + 1L);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

So now the version column works, but rest of Auditable fields `@CreatedAt, @CreatedBy,@LastModifiedDate and @LastModifiedBy` are not set!!

**Edit2**

Created a new ApplicationListener like below. In this case both my custom listener and Spring's RelationalAuditingListener are getting called. But still it doesn't solve the problem. Because the order of listeners[custom one followed by spring's] making the `markAudited` to invoke `markUpdated` instead of `markCreated`, since the version column is already incremented. I tried to make my Listener be the `LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` still no luck.

My custom listener here

```
public class CustomRelationalAuditingEventListener
    implements ApplicationListener<BeforeSaveEvent>, Ordered {

@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(BeforeSaveEvent event) {

    Object entity = event.getEntity();
    // handler.markAudited(entity);

    if (BaseDataModel.class.isAssignableFrom(entity.getClass())) {
        BaseDataModel baseDataModel = (BaseDataModel) entity;

        if (baseDataModel.getVersion() == null) {
            baseDataModel.setVersion(0L);
        } else {
            baseDataModel.setVersion(baseDataModel.getVersion() + 1L);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getOrder() {
    return LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you create a separate question for the problem with auditing, or describe why you think it is related to the version/optimistic locking issue?
In any case please show the relevant code: attributes & configuration.

Comment: The Auditable fields weren't related to version column increment nor the optimistic lock. It just clashed with the BeforeSaveEvent fired to handle the auditable fields, when I created a BeforeSaveEvent to handle the version column. But I see now that the PR is in place to handle the version column incrementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have to increment the version manually and there is no optimistic locking, i.e. the version is only used for checking if an entity is new.

There is an open [issue for support of optimistic locking](https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJDBC/issues/DATAJDBC-219) and there is even [a PR open for it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/pull/124). 
Therefore it is likely that this feature will be available with an upcoming 1.1 milestone.

Comment: The PR didn't make it into 1.1 but version 2.0 of Spring Data JDBC will contain support for Optimistic Locking.